# Extjs Grid with autoload store did not reflect the paging toolbar when first loaded

Tags: extjs, grid, paging, autoload

I am working with Ext JS 5.0.1 and I just encountered one grid related issue. Any help would be appreciated.

1. A gridpanel in the View with a binding store from ViewModel.
2. A pagingtoolbar docked on the bottom of the grid and shares the same binding store from ViewModel.
3. Store definition in ViewModel with below config

Code:

```
autoLoad: true,
        params: {
            page: 1,
            start: 0,
            limit: 6
        },
        pageSize: 6
```

4. Everything worked great with auto load and pagination.

**The ISSUE I have**

Paging tool bar did not display the correct paging info after page loaded at the first time. It just said Page 0 of 0.

**My Solution**

I tried to listen the grid's afterrender event. But at that monment the store is empty (NOT loaded yet). So I just added a button called Load. Follow the below code handled in the ViewController and it worked great.

```
Code:
        var grid = this.getReferences().customerGrid,
            store = grid.getStore();


        store.load();
```

**The Answer I want**

How to make the paging tool bar work with the auto load config and without the manual loading?

I just put full version of code on [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295182-Grid-with-autoload-store-did-not-reflect-the-paging-toolbar-when-first-loaded&p=1077677#post1077677).

Comment: I think it might be a bug. As a workaround, you could add a listener in your grid's afterrender event, and then add: 

grid.getViewModel().bind('{myStoreBindKey}', function (store) {
                store.load();
            });

Comment: Also, just FYI, you should use this.lookupReference( 'customerGrid' ) to retrieve the reference.

Comment: Thanks existdissolve. I've tried this approach. Actually, the afterrender's first param is the grid. We don't have to use the lookupReference. But the grid does NOT have the method called getViewModel. I just used getStore and find the store is NOT loaded yet. Maybe it is the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

What is your first request showing? (firebug or so)
I think you will see something like 
limit 25
start 0
page 1
and not your config. You should pass your params dierect to autoLoad Config

```
autoLoad: {
   page: 1,
   start: 0,
   limit: 6
}
```

params config can be used within load() method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, params worked great for data loading, so did your code. But the same result is the pagingtoobar still displayed 'Page 0 of 0' at the first time.

Comment: i am to lazy to make a fiddle. you can try both configs and inspect params. You will than see, that your way default settings will be used. anyway it won't fix your problem. May you provide some more code especially binding and vm.